# Java - Find hash table with maximum size

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following data structure:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String,Double>>

----------------
|     | a    2 |
| 100 | b    1 |    
|     | c    2 |
----------------
|     | a    2 |
| 101 | c    2 |    
----------------
|     | a    2 |
| 102 | b    1 |    
|     | c    2 |
----------------
```

GOAL: get the ID of the outer map containing the inner map with the maximum size.

For example, `100` or `102`, which both contain an inner map whose size is 3.

How can I use `Stream API`, for example?

Comment: What attempt have you made so far?

Comment: @khelwood I iterated over the outer map keys, saving the size of the inner map and the corresponding outer ID. But I have about 20000 keys: the process is very slow, so I need a faster way.

Comment: Not bad a start. I guess doing the lookup each time for all the keys is pretty timeconsuming. Are the inner Maps accessed indepenently or only through your outer map? I.E. do you have control over when the inner maps are added to /deleted from in a single place? If so, you could have a reference to the max and update it on each add/remove to an inner map ... a lot of "Ifs" still ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give an output of 100 or the key with Maximum elements.

```
map.keySet().stream().max((v1, v2) -> {
                return Integer.compare(map.get(v1).size(), map.get(v2).size());
            })
```

or using Comparator

```
map.keySet().stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(v -> map.get(v).size()))
```

Complete Code:

```
Map<Integer,Map<String,Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,Double> map100 = new HashMap<>();
map100.put("a", 2.0);
map100.put("b", 1.0);
map100.put("c", 2.0);
Map<String,Double> map101 = new HashMap<>();
map101.put("a", 2.0);
map101.put("b", 1.0);
Map<String,Double> map102 = new HashMap<>();
map102.put("a", 2.0);
map102.put("b", 1.0);
map102.put("c", 2.0);
map102.put("d", 2.0);
map.put(100, map100);
map.put(101, map101);
map.put(102, map102);

System.out.println(map.keySet().stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(v -> map.get(v).size())));

System.out.println(map.keySet().stream().max((v1, v2) -> {
    return Integer.compare(map.get(v1).size(), map.get(v2).size());
}));
```

Comment: Note that this can produce tons of hash lookups for larger maps. If you know that you’ll need the keys *and* values, you should iterate over the `entrySet` in the first place instead of iterating over the `keySet` and doing a lookup per key. I.e. `map.entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue( Comparator.comparingInt(Map::size))).map(Map.Entry::getKey)`

Comment: Holger - Excellent suggestion, This indeed results in a lot of unnecessary lookups which can be avoided. @Nicolas gave a good example explaining this.

Answer (score 5):

```
map.values().stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Map::size)).get()
```

is what you're looking for.

```
map.keySet().stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(k -> map.get(k).size()))
```

or the above if you want the key, not the map.
Test code:

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("A", 1);
        map2.put("B", 2);
        map2.put("C", 3);
        map.put(100, map2);
        map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("A", 1);
        map2.put("B", 2);
        map.put(101, map2);
        System.out.println(map.values()
                              .stream()
                              .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Map::size)).get());
```

Comment: @Tunaki he doesn't :) `100 or 102`

Comment: Only one value is sufficient, since I have the following hypothesis: two outer maps with the size size have two inner maps with the same keys.

Comment: @Fab is getting that map sufficient or you'd prefer the index?

Comment: But the returned Map doesn't contain the Key anymore right? Like 100 or 102 information is lost.

Comment: @BandiKishore yea, upvoted your answer. It's better. I focused on the map itself

Comment: @xenteros Yes, I need the index, not the map.

Answer (score 5):

To get the key of the outer map of **any entries** that have the biggest map as value, the code could be:

```
int id = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(Map::size)))
    .get() // May throw a NoSuchElementException if there is no max
    .getKey();
```

Another approach allowing to get the value as `Optional<Integer>` as proposed by [**@Holger**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) which avoids to get a `NoSuchElementException` in case we have no max when the map is empty for example.

```
Optional<Integer> id = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(Map::size)))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

---

Please note, that those approaches are more efficient than going through the keys and calling `map.get(k).size()` to get the size of the inner map because you do unnecessary map lookups that you don't do when iterating over the entries directly as proposed by those approaches.

Comment: You may also use `Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(Map::size))` as comparator. And if the presence of a maximum isn’t guaranteed (i.e. the map might be empty), replace `.get().getKey()` by `.map(Map.Entry::getKey)` to get an `Optional<Integer>`.